# Start python celery task permanently Linux command

Tags: python, linux, celery

I am running celery task on a remote server I am using following command to run celery:

```
python manage.py celery worker --beat
```

celery tasks are running according to schedule but when click `ctrl+c` or close session windows it stops. 
I need a command to run celery permanently.

Answer (score 2):

You can run it as daemon. See:

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html

Comment: Please rate this answer if it has been helpful for you.